# Check if the last result of a parser sequence corresponds to a predicate - FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I would like to create a parser that parses data names from modules, for example:

```
MyModule.myData // (a module name and a member of the module)
```

To do this, I would like to analyze all the identifiers that are separated by a point. The problem is that I can apply a predicate to all these parsers, but I couldn't know which one will be the last in the sequence, in this case I would like the last identifier to start with a lowercase letter. 
Here's the code I have:

```
type QualName = (string list) * string

let rec identifierP predicate =
    many1Satisfy
        (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c || c = ''') >>=
    fun id ->
        if isDigit id.[0]
        then fail "Error: starts by a number"
        else
            if predicate id
            then preturn id
            else fail "Error: identifier don't match with the predicate"

and private idP_capitalized (id: string) = System.Char.IsUpper id.[0]
and private idP_lowered (id: string) = System.Char.IsLower id.[0]
and private idP_nospecified (_: string) = true

and private qualName lastPredicate =
    (sepBy1 (identifierP idP_capitalized (* => from module(s) *)) (pstring "."))
    |>> fun lst -> (lst |> List.rev |> List.tail |> List.rev, lst.Last())
```

If I apply a subsequent analysis with the predicate, like the code below, in case of error, there is no possibility of going back (like with a simple FParsec `fail'):

```
and private qualName lastPredicate =
    (sepBy1 (identifierP idP_capitalized (* => from module(s) *)) (pstring "."))
    |>> fun lst ->
        if lastPredicate lst = false
        then failwith "Error: identifier don't match with the predicate"
        else (lst |> List.rev |> List.tail |> List.rev, lst.Last())
```

How could I do such an analysis, with parsing errors from FParsec if there are any?